# ubuntu 11 runlevel

Tags: ubuntu, runlevel

probably a simple question, but i think im wording things wrongly to the googles:

i have a ubuntu 11 server that 90% of the time runs headless, and is only accessed over ssh.

i use it as a workstation occasionally, and use the GUI when i do. however, i do not want GDM / graphical login stuff to run at boot and waste resources.

tl;dr -- i want to have gnome installed, but not run until i login and "startx"

easy way to ensure i boot to a CLI only in ubuntu 11?

Answer (score 1):

> sudo update-rc.d -f gdm remove

Comment: hrm, the above didnt work. rebooted and it still came up with GDM / ubuntu graphical login.

Comment: i was able to configure using this (slightly dated) but still 100% functional tutorial.

http://tuxthink.blogspot.com/2010/08/modifying-run-level-in-ubuntu-1004.html

thanks for the help!